# Systemd: Requires AND Wants

Tags: systemd

I've got a Systemd service which has both a Requires and a Wants section. i.e.

```
[Unit]
Description="Some service"
Requires= some-unit.target
Wants= some-unit.target
```

Is this incorrect or is it valid to have both?

What is the behaviour? i.e. does it fall back on Wants behaviour if unable to satisfy Requires?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question about the validity, that can be checked with `systemd-analyze verify`. It reports no errors when using the combination. However, perhaps it should. The combination expresses a confused intent.

> What is the behaviour? i.e. does it fall back on Wants behaviour if unable to satisfy Requires?

To be certain of the behavior, mock up some simple dummy units and check.

My expectation is that `Wants=` is overridden by `Requires=` and has no affect. That's based on the docs in `man systemd.unit` which share that `Want=` is simply a weaker version of `Requires=`.

There are no indications in the documentation that the behavior of `Requires=` would be modified just because a `Want=` directive is also present.

For maximum clarity, pick which behavior you really want and remove the other directive.